# What version of Visual Studio to target windows XP builds?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio

I want to develop a business application using WPF/C# .NET. The application will have lots of modern gui widgets and functionality such as dockable views and a ribbon. The application should also run on Windows XP as well as Windows 7 and 8.

What Visual studio .NET version should I use? I've heard that in VS 2012/2013 you can't target xp. Is that the case?

Comment: You do realize that the end of life of XP is getting closer, do you? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/endofsupport.aspx

Comment: yes I do but I still have to target XP, I want to market my software in Africa where winXP still lingers on a lot of legacy systems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its more of .Net framework and not IDE specific.

`.Net 4.5 framework` cannot be installed on XP machines. So if you are talking about `development machines`, its true you `can't go with VS 2012/2013` since 4.5 in installed by default with them.

But if you are talking about `customer machines` here, you can use `Windows 7/8 for development with 2012/2013 IDE` but project should target `.Net 4.0 framework or below`.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to know

Answer (score 9):

Use Visual Studio 2013 and develop on a Windows 7/8 system.

You can target XP easily by just changing the .NET framework from 4.5 to **4.0**

UPDATE: As @hvd has stated in the comments, be sure you test your product on an XP machine (or on a machine that has only .NET 4.0)
http://news.kynosarges.org/2012/08/01/no-net-4-5-for-xp2003/

Comment: +1 but make sure to *test* on XP as well. .NET 4.5 replaces 4.0, and that fixes some bugs that will still affect XP users.

Answer (score 1):

I think Visual Studio 2013 natively supports .Net v4.5, which does not support Windows XP. Even VS2012 requires Windows 7.

And if you want to target XP then you can switch the .NET version to 4.0. So its about the framework rather than IDE

If you want a XP support on Visual Studio then you have to use the Visual Studio 2010 version.

Comment: The fact that VS2013 supports .NET 4.5 doesn't mean it doesn't support .NET 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0. It's not about what OS VS2013 can run on, it's about what OS the custom program can run on.

Comment: @hvd:- Updated my answer. Hope that makes it better!